# SQL*Plus editor in 10g

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have installed Oracle 10g on my machine but not able to run ed for edit option error:

> SP2-0110: Cannot create save file "afiedt.buf"

Please, help me out to solve this. I have already tried so many options for fix it.

Comment: http://www.itorian.com/2012/08/sp2-0110-cannot-create-save-file.html

Comment: Windows 7 professional.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file path where you are trying to save, check if the folder structure exists and you have write permission